# Issues with setfill in a member function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program over multiple files that reads out the time, but I am having trouble displaying the time in the desired format. More specifically, `setfill` appears to be causing me problems.

Here is the beginning of a very long error messages I recieve when compiling:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _CharT = char, 
_Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, 
std::char_traits<char> >&)(& std::cout)), std::setw(2)) << std::setfill 
[with _CharT = const char*](((const char*)"0"))’
```

Now, this message only appears when I have `setfill` in my member function. If I remove `setfill` there is no issues with output except the format is wrong.

The member function is:

```
Void Time::print()
{
    cout << setw (2) << setfill ("0") << hours << ":";
    cout << setw (2) << setfill ("0") << minutes << ":";
    cout << setw (2) << setfill ("0") << seconds << endl;
}
```

To be clear, I have included `iomanip` and `setw` has no problem working on its own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

setfill takes a char, it should be `'0'` instead of `"0"`

Answer (score 9):

In addition, if you are using a wstringstream, setfill wants a wchar.

Compare

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hours << ":";
```

with

```
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(L'0') << hours << ":";
```

Answer (score 2):

You should:

```
cout << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << hours << ":";
cout << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << minutes << ":";
cout << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << seconds << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

setfill takes a `char`, not a `char*`, so it should be `'0'`.

Comment: Note that `"0"` is a `const char *`, not a `char *`.